# Quick question about ODE solutions (trigonometry equality)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

After solving an ordinary differential equation, I got this solution:
$$ A\cos(\omega t + \phi) $$ where A and $\omega$ have fixed values (I don't see the relevance to bring them in, thus I won't).

My question is if I'm allowed to consider instead the solution as the following $$ B\cos(\omega (t - t_{0}) + \phi)$$ because that would simplify the calculations (namely, $\phi$ would be $0$).

I guess it is obvious because in that case $\omega t + \phi$ would be the same as $\omega t - \omega t_{0}$ but I still would like to know why I can use this and why this works, from a math point of view (first year though =)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
$$
A\cos(\omega (t - t_{0}) + \phi) =
A\cos(\omega t + \Phi)
$$
for some constant $\Phi$, namely $\Phi = \phi-\omega t_0$.  So if you are allowed
$$
A\cos(\omega t + \phi)
$$
for all values of the constant $\phi$, then you are also allowed $A\cos(\omega (t - t_{0}) + \phi)$ for all values of constants $t_0$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Exactly. That's a simple algebraic thing. I was thinking about how this new function is a translation relatively to the previous one but it isn't. It's **exactly the same**. Thanks for confirming me that